# Counting occurrences in files spyder python

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple program that allows me to scan a pattern list(patterns.txt) of 000 010 100 etc. against a sequence list(sequence.txt) 010100100010 etc.

The program should return
#number of occurrences of 0's and 1's on each line in the sequence file
#number of occurrences of each of the pattern in the pattern list against each line in the sequence file

-- my current code looks like this I know it doesn't look like a lot but I'm really new in this and am trying my best effort --

```
#reading and opening files
file1 = open('patterns.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('sequences.txt', 'r')
targetSeq = "001010101010000101011100010101"

#storing the lines in patterns.txt as list using slicing
with open('patterns.txt', 'r') as file1:
patternList = file1.readlines()
print(patternList)

with open('sequences.txt' , 'r') as file2:
#converting into list
sequencelist = file2.readlines()
for line in sequencelist:
    type = line.split(',')
    print(sequencelist)
    count = sequencelist.count(0)
    print(count)
```

*my main issue here is that I do not know how I can scan each line in file2 against the patterns in file1 and give individual line output as per the sample output. would really appreciate any help.

```
[output sample][1] 


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWqSU.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use nested loops. A few things were not clear like how similarity is calculated. You can use the below template to loop through the data.

```
with open('patterns.txt', 'r') as file1:
    patternList = file1.readlines()

with open('sequences.txt' , 'r') as file2:
    #converting into list
    sequencelist = file2.readlines()

for line in sequencelist:
    # is sequences.txt comma-separated or line separated or both? 
    # I'm assuming it's line separated
    print(sequencelist)
    count = sequencelist.count('0')
    print(count)
    for pattern in patternList:
        print(f"Number of occurrences of {pattern} : {len(re.findall(pattern, sequencelist))}"
```

Also, note that `re.findall()` was just from the top of my mind. You should dig in and try build your own logic block or look into other efficient options available.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
for line in sequencelist:
    for pattern in patternList:
        # Code to compare sequence with pattern
        .
        .
        .
```